# Extracting concatenated cpio archives

Tags: linux, initramfs, cpio

initramfs archives on Linux can consist of a series of concatenated, gzipped cpio files.

Given such an archive, how can one extract *all* the embedded archives, as opposed to only the first one?

The following is an example of a pattern which, while it appears to have potential to work, extracts only the first archive:

```
while gunzip -c | cpio -i; do :; done <input.cgz
```

---

I've also tried the [skipcpio helper from dracut](https://github.com/haraldh/dracut/blob/master/skipcpio/skipcpio.c) to move the file pointer past the first cpio image, but the following results in a corrupt stream (not at the correct point in the input) being sent to cpio:

```
# this isn't ideal -- presumably would need to rerun with an extra skipcpio in the pipeline
# ...until all files in the archive have been reached.
gunzip -c <input.cgz | skipcpio /dev/stdin | cpio -i
```

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood or the verbiage is just misleading, but the CPIO archives are not _each_ compressed. The overall set of concatenated archives is altogether gzip'd.

Comment: @sherrellbc, ...in hindsight (and as the answer I added to this question indicates I've learned since asking), that's a distinction without a difference. gunzip handles one stream and a series of streams concatenated together the exact same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian with the packages `amd64-microcode` / `intel-microcode` packages installed seems to use some kind of mess of an uncompressed `cpio` archive containing the CPU microcode followed by a `gzip` compressed `cpio` archive with the actual initrd contents. The only way I've ever been able to extract it is by using `binwalk` (`apt install binwalk`), which can both correctly list the structure:

```
binwalk /path/to/initrd
```

example output:

```
host ~ # binwalk /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel", file name length: "0x00000007", file size: "0x00000000"
120           0x78            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
244           0xF4            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode", file name length: "0x00000015", file size: "0x00000000"
376           0x178           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc", file name length: "0x00000036", file size: "0x00000000"
540           0x21C           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin", file name length: "0x00000026", file size: "0x00455C00"
4546224       0x455EB0        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
4546560       0x456000        gzip compressed data, has original file name: "mkinitramfs-MAIN_dTZaRk", from Unix, last modified: 2022-06-14 14:02:57
37332712      0x239A6E8       MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 9
```

and extract the separate parts:

```
binwalk -e /path/to/initrd
```

example output:

```
host ~ # binwalk -e /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel", file name length: "0x00000007", file size: "0x00000000"
120           0x78            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
244           0xF4            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode", file name length: "0x00000015", file size: "0x00000000"
376           0x178           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc", file name length: "0x00000036", file size: "0x00000000"
540           0x21C           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin", file name length: "0x00000026", file size: "0x00455C00"
4546224       0x455EB0        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
4546560       0x456000        gzip compressed data, has original file name: "mkinitramfs-MAIN_dTZaRk", from Unix, last modified: 2022-06-14 14:02:57
37332712      0x239A6E8       MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 9
```

This'll give you the separate parts in separate files, and now you can finally extract the proper `cpio` archive:

```
host ~ # ls -l _initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64.extracted 
insgesamt 187M
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4,0K 14. Jun 17:53 cpio-root/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114M 14. Jun 17:53 mkinitramfs-MAIN_dTZaRk
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39M 14. Jun 17:53 0.cpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35M 14. Jun 17:53 mkinitramfs-MAIN_dTZaRk.gz
```

```
host ~/_initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64.extracted # mkdir extracted
host ~/_initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64.extracted # cd extracted 
host ~/_initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64.extracted/extracted # cat ../mkinitramfs-MAIN_dTZaRk | cpio -idmv --no-absolute-filenames
[...]
```

```
host ~/_initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64.extracted/extracted # ll
insgesamt 28K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 14. Jun 17:55 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4,0K 14. Jun 17:55 conf/
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4,0K 14. Jun 17:55 etc/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 14. Jun 17:55 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 14. Jun 17:55 lib32 -> usr/lib32/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 14. Jun 17:55 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 14. Jun 17:55 libx32 -> usr/libx32/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K 14. Jun 16:02 run/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8 14. Jun 17:55 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4,0K 14. Jun 17:55 scripts/
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4,0K 14. Jun 17:55 usr/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6,2K 14. Jan 2021  init*
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/usr/lib/dracut/skipcpio $your-initrd-img | zcat | cpio -id --no-absolute-file-names
```

or else

```
/usr/lib/dracut/skipcpio $your-img | gunzip -c | cpio -id
```

(in FreeBSD there is no --no-absolute-file-names option to cpio)

This small program `skipcpio` if part of dracut package. But you can download the code (skipcpio.c) and compile it even under FreeBSD.

You need this when extracting dracut created initrd images, at least under RedHat-powered distros, like Fedora. It places a file called "early_cpio" into the image, so extracting your initramfs in a normal way known before will not work.

Comment: Ahh! You'll note that I mention skipcpio in my question -- it's one of the things I tried before asking -- but I assumed that it expected a cpio stream as input (as the name would imply), not a gzip stream. That said, I think the answer I already have is a better fit for the question ("[H]ow can one extract *all* the embedded archives[...]?"), since it extracts *all* cpio archives, as opposed to only the second one in the stream.

Comment: Of course, of course. Mine only relates to dracut-created archives, I even suspect, to RedHat-derived distros... Well, dracut IS powered by RH, is it not?? I've just put it here for further usage by those who might need this "weird" kind of thing. Like myself, when I needed to add modules to an existing initramfs to make a system boot in the first place, so running `dracut` to create one was out of question... Neither was it possible to chroot into that system from a Live CD, because I don't know a ZFS-aware Live CD distribution, and my Linux installation is ZFS-based.

Comment: How to get the `early_cpio` file?

Answer (score 6):

gunzip needs to be run only once (consuming all input), whereas cpio should be run once per embedded archive, like so:

```
gunzip -c <input.cgz | while cpio -i; do :; done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this manually with [`dd skip=`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html). On my Ubuntu 20.04, I can look at the first part (offset 0 blocks) with

```
# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic skip=0 | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

and then see the contents

```
# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic skip=0 | cpio -it
.
kernel
kernel/x86
kernel/x86/microcode
kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin
62 blocks
```

The second part is 62 blocks farther

```
# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic skip=62 | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

and again just a simple cpio archive, but larger this time

```
# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic skip=62 | cpio -it
kernel
kernel/x86
kernel/x86/microcode
kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc
kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin
5868 blocks
```

Now skip `5868 + 62` blocks into the initramfs

```
# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic skip=5930 | file -
/dev/stdin: LZ4 compressed data (v0.1-v0.9)
```

This time it is a compressed stream, so

```
# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic skip=5930 | lz4cat | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

And again we found the next (and final) cpio archive

```
# dd if=/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic skip=5930 | lz4cat | cpio -it
... lots of output
usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/watermark.png
usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png
var
var/cache
var/cache/fontconfig
var/cache/fontconfig/383ee5b3-5437-4bdc-87f6-cf314658a7c0-le64.cache-7
var/cache/fontconfig/575cffd4-ae01-4067-914f-7545fe566c1b-le64.cache-7
var/cache/fontconfig/CACHEDIR.TAG
var/cache/fontconfig/c467a813-186f-476e-880a-3770402989a9-le64.cache-7
var/cache/fontconfig/d912fc4e-f5b6-456d-a86d-e4c3ccbbefe9-le64.cache-7
var/lib
var/lib/dhcp
450460 blocks
```

Although, this only works, if the first streams are uncompressed. Otherwise, cpio wouldn't report the size into the initramfs, but of the uncompressed part.